# Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'SyndicationFeedFormatter' is not defined

Tags: asp.net

I’m having an issue where I keep getting this error message:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'SyndicationFeedFormatter' is not defined.

This issue is not because of my code. I did not touch any files for months and it has been working just fine. The issue started yesterday, when `godaddy.com` (my hosting company) decided to migrate and move my account to a new server. I submitted a product support ticket, but all I was getting from that was that I need to fix my code. I’m stuck now.
I appreciate any suggestions.
Website is http://www.baaboor.com

Comment: Seems like migration issue, try to find whether _SyndicationFeedFormatter_ is defined in source code _.cs file_ or in some DLL _.dll file_.

Comment: As Coder said, it seems like a migration issue, try compiling your source code to make sure its not an auto generated dll, or trye to manually remove an re-add the version of the `System.ServiceModel.dll` I assume you're using.

Comment: Check that the .NET framework version being used is the one you expect. `SyndicationFeedFormatter` moved from `System.ServiceModel.Web` to `System.ServiceModel` in the move from 3.5 to 4.